# how to make application sync offline entries with the application on web server in java?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, synchronization, vaadin, java-server

**> I need to make web system using java technology, but considering the

> internet dis-connectivity issues. I also need to make a desktop
>   version of that system... where user can do entries in system. My
>   requirement is this, if user click on a button or do any sort of
>   functionality at the end of a business day and all the entries that a
>   user have done in the past day should be updated in the Web System
>   online. User should not do entries again on the Web System.**

I don't know how to acheive this functionality using java technology...

I am using Java Hibernate and Java Vaadin Framework in the development of this Web System.

***Kindly Help me. Thanks is in advance. :)***

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin is a client-server framework. Your business code runs on the server side. Therefore you need a connection to the server. Offline mode is supported with the Vaadin TouchKit add-on mainly for mobile applications and not for heavy / a lot of views. More information [here](https://vaadin.com/blog/-/blogs/offline-mode-in-vaadin-apps-absurd-joke-or-a-real-solution). TouchKit works well with Google Chrome so you could give it a try.

Comment: nexus, sorry for late reply, i think vaadin touchkit will not help me. Is there any framework or technique in java by which i can achieve offline synchronization from my desktop application version to online Web application. and if any than how to use it?

Comment: @ShahjahanKhokhar with vaadin, TouchKit would be the only way for offline synchronization. There is no general answer to your question. It also depends on your project. Serving an offline application which runs within the browser is something completely else than a desktop application which runs for example in a JVM.